# using phpstorm and xampp and unable to create new project folder

Tags: php, configuration, xampp

I am really new to ubuntu and finally managed to get xampp working with xdebug and now i am trying to setup phpstorm but i run into problem.

My understanding is that the projects have to be created inside location `/opt/lampp/htdocs` so suppose I am creating a project called demo the project location will be `/opt/lampp/htdocs/demo` and this should be accessible via `localhost/demo`

However when I am in phpstorm and try to create a new empty project at location

`/opt/lampp/htdocs/demo`

[image]

I get this error
[image]

I will really appreciate any assistance in this.

Comment: It's always better to also include the error message as text in your question. Google doesn't index images ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately your target directory have no global permission so you can't create new directory or file in there!
open your **terminal** and type this:

```
cd /opt/lampp
sudo chmod 777 -R htdocs
```

first line navigate you to target directory and second line will change your permission with chmod command...